# Javascript conditional statemtent

Tags: javascript

I need to write some javascript in Adobe Business Catalyst that shows different lines of code based on whether the value "image" or "video" is returned from the database.

The name of the returned value is {tag_detailpage_image_or_video} which will return either image or video.

The code for displaying a video is:

```
<div class="shift-to-hero">
<p>{tag_left_video_detailpage_embed}</p>
</div>
```

The code for displaying an image is:

```
<figure class="article-image">{tag_left_detail_image_01}<br />
</figure>
```

I am not sure how to code this in javascript.

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have any code to show that explains what you're attempting to do?

Comment: This seems perfect for an [`if`/`else if`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) statement. Where are you stuck?

Comment: I am not that familiar with javascript but based on what I have read, it can be done with javascript.

Comment: http://www.daaq.net/old/javascript/index.php go there and read to learn basic javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At its simplest, you're looking for an `if`/`else if` statement based on what's contained within the variable `tag_detailpage_image_or_video`:

```
var wrapper, child;
if (tag_detailpage_image_or_video === 'video') {
    wrapper = document.createElement('div');
    child = document.createElement('p');
    wrapper.className = 'shift-to-hero';
    child.innerHTML = tag_left_video_detailpage_embed;
}
else if (tag_detailpage_image_or_video === 'image') {
    wrapper = document.createElement('figure');
    child = document.createElement('br');
    wrapper.innerHTML = tag_left_detail_image_01;
}
else {
    // neither option was returned
}
wrapper.appendChild(child);
document.body.appendChild(wrapper);
```

Though you could also use a `switch() {}`:

```
var wrapper, child;
switch (tag_detailpage_image_or_video) {
    case 'video' :
        wrapper = document.createElement('div');
        child = document.createElement('p');
        wrapper.className = 'shift-to-hero';
        child.innerHTML = tag_left_video_detailpage_embed;
        break;
    case 'image' :
        wrapper = document.createElement('figure');
        child = document.createElement('br');
        wrapper.innerHTML = tag_left_detail_image_01;
        break;
}
```

References:

- [`document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createElement).
- [`element.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.innerHTML).
- [`if...else`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else).
- [`Node.appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild).
- [`switch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch).

Comment: What scripting language is this?

Comment: This would be JavaScript, since that's the language tagged in the question. Is there a syntax problem you've seen?

Comment: Yes... No `<script>` blocks and embedded HTML should be using at the very least `document.write` though `document.createElement` might be better.  You can't just dump HTML in the middle of JavaScript like that.

Comment: Thanks guys. I wasn't trying to get over on the system, but my code looked jumbled and thought it would be better to start from scratch. I was attempting to force html into javascript using switch but it wasn't working. Will read up on stackoverflow rules before I post any more questions. Thanks for your time, guidance and direction.